# Clear input value in form

Tags: jquery, input

Due to IE8 transparancy issue I want to remove the value from a form field.

```
<input type="button" value="Something" />
```

I tried several variations of

```
$(' input[type="submit"], input[type="inputSubmit"], input[type="button"]').val('');
```

With no success. I know this should be simple.

I'd appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: You've got an answer that shows what you did wrong with the input type, but note that that will clear _all_ the fields of that type. When you said "a form field" did you mean a specific one?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/z9E8x/1/) is working fine for me all the way back to IE7

```
$('input[type="button"]').val('');
```

The result is a button with no text.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
$('input[type=text]')
```

Make sure the input's type is explicitly set to text, or it might fail.

Comment: Thanks fivedigit but I had better make my question clearer. I had not indented the first code block so it did not display. Question updated